# Craft 3 image asset getUrl() not showing

Tags: craft3, image

I came across an interesting issue. I'm using Craft CMS 3.0.0-RC14 and non of my image paths are showing but the title and the file name does.

```
{% set image = nav.navLogo.one() %}
{{image.title}} // works
{{image.fileName}} // works
{{image.getUrl()}} // no output, not even error
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you enable the `assets for this source have public URLs` in your volume settings in the cp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to enable "assets for this source have public URLs" in the volume settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to this post another possible solution if your "Assets for this source have public URLs" is turned on, but images are still not showing. I had my wires crossed in how I have the Base URL of the overall site set in relation to the Base URL in the Assets volume. In my particular case, the following settings finally got things working and all the images show up with getUrl() as they should. Hopefully this is helpful to others banging their heads trying to figure this out!

**In Assets/Volume:**
Base URL = **/images**
File System Path = **/images**

**In Settings/Sites:**
Base URL = **@web/**

Comment: The use of `@web` in your sites is being discouraged